# What is this white, ribbed, box shaped object attached to a somewhat-remote tree near Lake Chelan?

Tags: united-states, manmade-object-identification

While hiking near Lake Chelan (Washington, USA), I noticed this item affixed to the tree located at [48.150978, -120.493732](https://goo.gl/maps/jCUZFEpNvaxHSo5AA):

[image: Overall]

The tree in question is a short hike from a boat landing and right off a trail, but the area overall is fairly remote (designated wilderness).

I was unable to find any markings or other identification clues on the object. It appears to have been placed a while ago, as the screws holding it have been pulled almost completely out of the tree. The item primarily comprises a white, ribbed, rounded rectangular prism approximately 7x5x6".

[image: Crop]

Comment: Did it appear the container could be opened? First thought was that it may be a Geocache, or what's left of one.

Comment: If this is a geocache, I want to emphasize that it was placed by a *highly* irresponsible cache owner- no identifying markings, causing damage to nature, among other factors.  Alternate hypothesis:  Related to introducing the tiny wasps that help control pests like gypsy moths.  I don't know most of the details, but these wasps are bred in labs, and then colonies placed in effected areas, but I recall those colonies were usually in something like a paper cup, not plastic or metal.  This is pure guessing.

Answer (score 6):

Possibilities:

- Some form of remote sensor,  Perhaps they wanted to monitor microclimate values of temp and humidity on a long term basis.
- Bug trap.  The container fastens with wingnuts, while the bracket appears to be screwed or nailed.  By implication the container was intended to be replaced/inspected multiple times.  Bug trap would fit this, as would pollen trap.

Finding more information.

Since you have coordinates, find out what national/state forest/park that your location corresponds to.  Drop by their office and see if they have a record of any research projects in that area.  They are likely to redirect you to one or more scientists connected to a local university.

Comment: The fact that the tree fixture is damaged and is very close to falling off could be used to justify the enquiry.

Comment: We could also use the state of the object to justify calling it "litter".

Comment: My first guess was going to be related to geocaching, but I could not find one supposed to be in that location